# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'currency' not found on type edu.bsu.Country with Lombok @Data

Tags: java, jsp, el, lombok

I am receiving PropertyNotFoundException when I am trying to get Lombok `@Data` field value using EL on jsp page

```
Currency-> ${country.currency}
```

But if I am trying to get field value using getter

```
Currency-> ${country.getCurrency()}
```

This line is working fine

Another fields can be received without any problems

The whole code of the class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Country implements Comparable<Country> {

    private String countryID;
    private String name;
    private String currency;
    

    public String getCountryInfo() {
        return getCountryID() + " - " + getName();
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Country object) {
        return this.getCountryID().compareTo(object.getCountryID());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
            return false;
        Country countryBo = (Country) obj;
        return countryID != null && countryID.equals(countryBo.countryID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(countryID, name, currency);
    }

    public Country(String countryID, String name) {
        super();
        this.countryID = countryID;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I've tried to create new field "test" and this field also throws PropertyNotFoundException, but fields countryID and name working fine

Now I am using workaround with the getters, but I wondering why this problem happens...

I will be glad to any explanation of what the problem is

Thanks

Comment: I think the `@Data` annotation is some Lombok thing that generates those getters/setters

Comment: @Erik yes this is lombok,I've decompiled deployed classes on servers, lombok generates correct getters and setters, also I've tried to write getters and setters manually and I am receiving the same errors

Comment: I don't have an explanation for this -- I would have to step through line by line with a debugger to find out.